# Tricky convex hull problem

Tags: geometry, convex-hulls

Let $V$ be an arbitrary set. Given that $\sup_{x\in V} \langle x,u\rangle \ge 1$ for all unit $u\in \mathbb{R}^n,$ show that convex hull of $V$ contains oepn unit ball centered at 0.

This looks easy at first but I have spent hours thinking about it to no avail.

Comment: Do you mean the open unit ball?

Comment: It is a closed ball.

Comment: @Daniel Li. it should be the open ball then I think, since if $V$ is the open unit ball, it satisfies the hypothesis. Also speaking of potential clarifications, $V$ does not need to contain points at every direction; a triangle with. vertices $(100, 0)$ and $(-100, \pm 100)$. Did you mean to write. conv(V) contains points at every direction?

Comment: Then the result is not true, if $V$ is the open unit ball then the above holds, but clearly the open ball does not contain the closed ball.

Comment: V can be a closed ball as well. I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: You need to clarify what you are asking. If $V$ is the open unit ball then the $\sup$ inequality holds but clearly $V$ does not contain the closed unit ball.

Comment: If V is closed ball, the hypothesis is still true. Is it not?

Comment: V is arbitrary set.

Comment: I don't really want to answer speculative questions in the comments. Fix your questions.

Comment: It is, but you are trying to make a claim for all V in your hypothesis

Comment: @copper.hat do you know the answer if the OP were to change it to open unit ball?

Comment: @copper.hat There is no speculation. If you can prove that V contains an open ball, it would be great but I don't know why it has to be open

Comment: @DanielLi the claim should say "the convex hull of V contains the open unit ball" otherwise, if you insist on the "closed unit ball" the claim is false, since there is a set V (namely, the open unit ball), that satisfies the hypothesis, but does not contain the unit ball.

Comment: As written, the assertion is not true. If we take the open unit ball for $V$, then the condition $\sup_{x \in V} \langle x, u\rangle \geqslant 1$ for all $u$ of unit length holds, but the convex hull of $V$ is $V$ itself, which doesn't contain the _closed_ unit ball. You get a correct assertion if you either modify the claim to "contains the open unit ball", or to "the closed convex hull of $V$ contains the closed unit ball".

Comment: @DanielFischer I see. I saw this in a paper where the author was not clear in making this distinction between open and closed ball--it is written as $B(0,1)$. Do you have a proof for the open ball?

Comment: Do you know that the convex hull of $V$ is the intersection of all half-spaces that contain $V$?

Comment: @DanielLi Here is a more general statement you can prove: if $ \sup_{x \in A} <x, u> \geq \sup_{x \in B} <x, u> $ for all unit u, for A, B closed convex sets, show that $ B \subset A $.
If you know convex conjugates, that will immediately give the proof

Comment: A general result (for convex sets) is that the support function dominates another iff the closure of the sets follows the corresponding inclusion. Hahn Banach gives a straightforward proof.

Comment: @DanielLi Generally (but not always) I have seen $B(0,1)$ used for the open ball.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $u$ lies in the open unit ball but $u \notin V$. The Hahn Banach shows that there
is some unit vector $h$ such that $\langle h, x \rangle \le \langle h, u \rangle $ for
all $x \in V$.
Hence $1 \le \langle h, u \rangle \le \|u\| < 1$ which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

(Separating Hyperplane Theorem) Let $A$ and $B$ be two disjoint nonempty convex subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then there exist a nonzero vector $v$ and a real number $c$ such that
:$\langle x, v \rangle \ge c \, \text{ and } \langle y, v \rangle \le c$
for all $x$ in $A$ and $y$ in $B$; i.e., the hyperplane $\langle \cdot, v \rangle = c$, $v$ the normal vector, separates $A$ and $B$.

Suppose that $u \in B(0,1)$ but $u \notin conv(V)$. Then let $A:=\{u\},B:=conv(V)$ in the theorem. Then there exist a nonzero vector $v$ and a real number $c$ such that:

$$\langle u, v \rangle \ge c \implies \|v\|_2> c$$

and $$ \sup_{y \in conv(V)}\langle y, v \rangle \le c \implies \|v\|_2\le \sup_{y \in V}\langle y, v \rangle \le c$$

The former implication is by Cauchy Schwarz inequality and that the $B(0,1)$ is open;  the latter implication is by our assumption. This gives the desired contradiction.